# Passing two objects to EJS view from two different SQL queries using promisses in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, promise, ejs

I am trying to build a EJS form with three fields and I need to pass *two sets of data* to it at the same time: users and books using promises. Unfortunatly books are not getting passed and stay 'undefined'. I cannot figure out why.

**Form**

1. Textfield (irrelevant for this example)
2. Dropdown box with a list of users
3. Dropdown box with a list of books

For (2) and (3) I query my mysql database to get the data so that I can fill the form drop-down-boxes.

**/controller.js**

```
const User       = require('../models/user.js');
const Book       = require('../models/book.js');

    exports.getAddNeueAusleihe = (req, res, next) => {

      // storing users and books in this object
      let view_data_for_my_view = {};

      // fetch users for dropdown-box nr.1
      User.fetchAll()

      .then(([users_rows]) => {
        view_data.users = users_rows;
        
        // fetch books for dropdown-box nr. 2
        return Book.fetchAll(([books_rows]) => {
        view_data.books = books_rows;
       });
      })

      .then(() => {
        
        // send data to view
        res.render('neue-ausleihe.ejs', {

          users: view_data.users,
          books: view_data.books,
          pageTitle:  'Neue Ausleihe'

        });
      });
    }
```

The User-fetch works fine. But the Book-fetch does return "undefined", although the SQL code in the books model works fine. It actually jumps into the books model, but does not get the values to the view. Here is my SQL-code for models.

**/models/user.js**

```
const db = require('../util/database.js');

module.exports = class User {
    constructor(id, name) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
    }

    static fetchAll() {
      return db.execute('SELECT * from dbuser WHERE UserFlag = "active"');
   };
}
```

**/models/books.js**

```
const db = require('../util/database.js');    

module.exports = class Book {
        constructor(id, name) {
          this.id = id;
          this.name = name;
        }
    
        static fetchAll() {
          return db.execute('SELECT * from books WHERE status = "free"');
       }
    }
```

Comment: What does `db.execute` return? BTW you don't have to use `static` in javascript. It's not Java. You can create functions outside of classes.

It's strange that I don't see a `new Book` anywhere, since the intent looks like it's supposed to represent Book entities.

Comment: Both 'db.execute' return proper results. Basically for the user it is '(user_id, username, userflag)'. For books it is '(book_id, book_name, status)'. There are some more attributes, but they are meaningless to this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `db.execute` returns a promise that resolves to an array, for which the first entry is the actual result, your code should look more like this:

```
exports.getAddNeueAusleihe = (req, res, next) => {

  // storing users and books in this object
  const view_data = {};

  // fetch users for dropdown-box nr.1
  User.fetchAll()
   .then(([users_rows]) => {
      view_data.users = users_rows;
    
      // fetch books for dropdown-box nr. 2
      return Book.fetchAll();
    })
    .then([book_rows] => {
      view_data.books = books_rows;
    })
    .then(() => {
    
      // send data to view
      res.render('neue-ausleihe.ejs', {
        users: view_data.users,
        books: view_data.books,
        pageTitle:  'Neue Ausleihe'
      });
    });
}
```

Bonus version:

```
exports.getAddNeueAusleihe = async(req, res, next) => 
    
  // send data to view
  res.render('neue-ausleihe.ejs', {
     pageTitle:  'Neue Ausleihe',
     users: (await User.fetchAll())[0]
     books: (await Book.fetchAll())[0]
  });

}
```

Even as the person writing this, it still blows my mind how much more readable async/await-based code is vs promise chains.

Comment: Yeh! That did the job. I wonder, if there is a way to solve this without constructing the "view_data" object? Because view_data actually becomes a compound object that carries two different categories of data - users and books.

Comment: Yes, with async you certainly can. I'll update the 'bonus version'